# Nested mongoose update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use mongoose to write a node program that use to do the basic sort and update. I was able to get the sorting part, but when I try to update the result, the doc doesn't seem like updated, even the callback is called.
Here is my code

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
db_connection= mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/weather');
var schema =  mongoose.Schema;
var any=new schema({});
var ary=db_connection.model('data',any,'data');
var promise=ary.find({}).distinct('State').exec();
promise.then(function(docs){
 for (var i=0; i<docs.length; i++){
  ary.find({State:docs[i]},{},{sort:{State:-1, Temperature:-1}}).limit(1).exec(function(err, doc){
    ary.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:doc[0]._id},{$set:{month_high:'true'}}).exec(function(err, data){
      console.log(data +" updated sucessfully" );
      console.log(doc[0]._id);//output id
      console.log((doc[0].State));//output undefined
    });
  });
 }
});
```

and here is what the database doc looks like(from Mongo university M101JS  HW2-2)

> { _id: 54b751970d79037642e96a47,   Day: 11,   Time: 1150,   State:
>   'California',   Airport: 'LAX',   Temperature: 81,   Humidity: 32,
>   'Wind Speed': 5,   'Wind Direction': 50,   'Station Pressure': 29.63, 
>   'Sea Level Pressure': 151,   __v: 0 } { _id: 54b751970d79037642e96884,
>   Day: 23,   Time: 1654,   State: 'Vermont',   Airport: 'BTV',
>   Temperature: 57,   Humidity: 78,   'Wind Speed': 13,   'Wind
>   Direction': 170,   'Station Pressure': 29.1,   'Sea Level Pressure':
>   982,   __v: 0 } { _id: 54b751970d79037642e96ce4,   Day: 8,   Time:
>   1453,   State: 'Florida',   Airport: 'ORL',   Temperature: 83,
>   Humidity: 55,   'Wind Speed': 5,   'Wind Direction': 190,   'Station
>   Pressure': 29.97,   'Sea Level Pressure': 195,   __v: 0 } { _id:
>   54b751970d79037642e9700d,   Day: 11,   Time: 1453,   State: 'New
>   Mexico',   Airport: 'SAF',   Temperature: 57,   Humidity: 32,   'Wind
>   Speed': 11,   'Wind Direction': 340,   'Station Pressure': 23.87,
>   'Sea Level Pressure': 174,   __v: 0 }

To make the thing even funnier, when I tried to debug the code using the last two lines, one output as expected and the second one doesn't. Can someone please explain to me what i did wrong or miss? Thanks

Comment: There's a lot going on here, but one problem I see is that [`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) takes the `_id` value as a parameter, not a query object.

Comment: Thx Johnny, good point, but i also tried to use update instead of  findByIdAndUpdate, both have the same problem :P

Comment: Just noticed that `ary` doesn't define a schema. Updates won't work properly if you do that. Not much point in using Mongoose without defining a schema for your models.

Comment: Thx again, but why when I tried to print the distinct states after the promise.then statement the system can print out the different states?